# How do I remove a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

//function del () {

var x= new Date ();

var date= x.getDate ();

var hours= x.getHours();

var minutes=x.getMinutes();

var sec= x.getSeconds();

document.write(minutes +":"+ sec )


if (minutes=="33"){

//alert ("time is over")

document.getElementById('airtel').removeChild(airtel);

}

//}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="airtel">
<div id="vodafone">vodaphone</div>

<div id="idea">idea</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to explain what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) Library removes the pain from using Javascript for handling the DOM, i sugest you give it a try.

But if you just want that working in native Javascript, what you need to do is traverse to the parentNode and then remove the child you want.

```
var element = document.getElementById('airtel');
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not working, could be please give me more suggestions

Comment: This should work, please tell us of errors. Seeing your date code, I suspect something really different is not working. You only check if minutes==33 when the document is loaded. You need to set up a timer and do that when minutes reach 33 or some other time.

Comment: According to the tests i made this works fine, but tell me your what's your browser and if you got any Javascript exceptions and i'll check it later.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are better off using jQuery with it's [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the element of 'airtel' then remove it from it's parent, which is the Body tag.

```
var airtel= document.getElementById('airtel');    
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(airtel);
```